# Reading and writing complex data types in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, uwp

What is the easiest way to save and recall complex data types to a local storage folder?
For example, Let's say I have a person class:

```
 class Person
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Person()
        {
            Person Ben = new SDKTemplate.Person()
            {
                Name = "Ben",
                Age = 24
            };
        }
```

How would I save my Person object (Ben) to a local storage folder.
Better yet, How would I save a list and also read from that file?
I have looked and the closest answers have said I should use SQL or only told me how to read and right string data.

Comment: Read up on Serialization, it is a good way to go, and not too hard: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [NewtonSoft.Json library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to serialize your object (or list of objects) :

```
 // serialize your objects list and write the serialized string to a file:
 string serializedPersons = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personsList);
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\path.txt", serializedPersons);
 .
 .
 // read your file and deserialize the json text:
 string personsFileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\path.txt");
 var persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(personsFileText );
```

Answer (score -1):

you could convert your object to a json string, store the json in the text file, and then when you read the file you convert that json string back into your model object.